# How to manage embedded audio resources in Delphi (similar to TImageList)?

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource

I need to manage a large number of diverse embedded resources (such as wav files, pictures etc.).

For images, we have things like TImageList which makes it very easy and comfortable to embed, access and use icons at runtime.

I wonder if there is an easy, comfortable library component for other resources, such as wav files, too, so I can access them easily in this manner, populate menus with them or play them, for example:

```
PlayWav(WavLibrary.ItemIndex(1));
```

instead of

```
PlayWav('C:\Users\Documents\sounds\wav1.wav');
```

which is obviously error-prone and needs loads of extra handling (deploying the files in the right directory during install time, ensure permissions, prevent them from being deleted, copied etc., enumerate them and lastly making sure to call the right path from the app at runtime).

Doing it with rc files and resource streams etc. seems comparably cumbersome.

If there is a general library component that can manage embedded resources of other kinds (not just wav) I would also like to know that.

If there isn't, how would you go about this in the most time-saving and easy way?

Comment: The Project menu has a _Resources and Images_ entry which lets you manage any resources pretty comfortable. A small routine to get the resource by name and play it should not be that difficult.

Comment: Thanks Uwe, but it looks like this is only for bmp, cur, fnt, gif, ico, ttf and a few other formats, not audio files, according to the filter in the Open file dialog.
If I work around that (adding wav files even though it doesn't seem to be supported), could you briefly give me an example of such a small routine that would let me call on these resources in a manner similar to a filepath string? Thanks!

Comment: To further complicate things, I couldn't find a way for e.g. TMediaPlayer to "LoadfromStream", so even once I have them in the resources and images list, how can I use them easily?

Comment: You can include any resource with this dialog. Use RC_DATA if it doesn't match one of the others. If TMediaPlayer doesn't support streams, you are bound to a file anyway. At least you can save the resource to a temporary file to play.

Comment: You can play a wave from a resource ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/playing-wave-resources)). However that's not the case in general for different media types. F.i. if you wanted to play a midi you'd have to program it or use a library. ... The "resources and images" dialog can manage any kind of resource, you can even define your own type.

Comment: So I tried: Adding wav file to Project | Resources and Images as you suggested (it's a standard 8kHz 16bit Mono wave file).
Adding the line "{$R 'ProjectnameResource.rc'}" at the top of the main unit (thought this would happen automatically, but it didn't).
Calling the resource from a button with "PlaySound('MyWavFile',0,SND_ASYNC);"
No luck: On compiling, I get the dcc32 error E2161: "RLINK32: Unsupported 16bit resource in file ".......\ProjectnameResource.rc"
It's driving me nuts :-(
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: - Start blank new VCL Forms project. - Bring on "resources and images" - Click the "add" button. - Set file type to "any type" in the file open dialog. - Select your *.wav file. - Type in a resource name e.g.: "Resource_1" - Type in "WAVE" in the resource type edit. - Click OK. - Hit shift+f9. (Open the dialog again and hit OK again  before rebuilding - probably for XE2 only).

Comment: Don't put anything in the code editor - no "{$R..." or anything. Use "mmsystem" in your form unit. Type `if not PlaySound('Resource_1', HInstance, SND_ASYNC or SND_RESOURCE) then RaiseLastOSError;` somewhere, f.i. in a button click handler. Run. Click.

Comment: Point in these comments being *"there is no built in way to manage embedded audio resources similar to an image list"*.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @SertacAkyuz - this works. I believe setting WAVE in the resource type edit did the trick! I was confused, as Uwe wrote to use "RC_DATA" above and that didn't quite work. However, I'll be able to work with the solution you provided. It's not quite as simple as a TImageList but it'll do. Thank you again for your patience and explaining in clear steps! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user - You're welcome. Now you have got it working, you might want to remove "RaiseLastOSError" because "PlaySound" is not documented to set the last error. (for testing, that was for the "LoadResource" call from winmm.dll).